# Real server-client C# program over internet

Tags: c#, sockets, server

Simple question, but after weeks of search no luck. I need to create a server-client program. Everything works well with localhost, but I need it over the internet. I work under Linux (Ubuntu).

Server:

```
public class SocketServer
{
    private const int PORT_NO = 8001;

    public SocketServer()
    {
        //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO);
        Console.WriteLine("Socket server started.");
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            //---incoming client connected---
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
            var nwStream = client.GetStream();
            var buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            //---read incoming stream---
            var bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

            //---convert the data received into a string---
            var dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine($"{dataReceived}");
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
public class Client
{
    private const int PORT_NO = 8001;
    private const string SERVER_IP = "xxx.xx.246.1";

    public void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var textToSend = Console.ReadLine();

            //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
            var client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
            var nwStream = client.GetStream();
            var bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend ?? string.Empty);

            //---send the text---
            Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + textToSend);
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

For IP I used [www.whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org), and I got an error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Connection refused
```

What am I missing? Is there some real example, no just with localhost?

Comment: Did you set up your router to forward the port to your server? And did you check for firewalls blocking the port?

Comment: whatsmyip will return the address of your NAT box, which is going to be your router / wifi AP. you need to setup port forwarding on it, to forward traffic that comes in on port 8001 to the same port insode your network

Comment: see https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-port-forward#:~:text=To%20forward%20ports%20on%20your%20router%2C%20log%20into%20your%20router,you%20might%20have%20to%20upgrade.

Comment: also note that your receive code will need to loop until it has received all the data you send